# How can I write a .htaccess redirect to find all numbers?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, numbers, hyperlink

I'm trying to figure out a regular expression that will find some numbers in a URL and use them in the URL I redirect to.

```
Redirect 301 /page.php?id=95485666 http://test.com/profile/info/id/95485666
```

i was thinking maybe

```
Redirect 301 /page.php?id=([0-9]+) http://test.com/profile/info/id/$1
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Also, if I do a 301 redirect, how long do i have to keep the code in the .htaccess file? when is Google gonna figure out that the new link is the good one?

Comment: You should take everything from "Also..." and make it a separate question.  It's not a good idea to try to squeeze multiple questions into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in the `Redirect` directive (nor in a `RedirectMatch`/`RewriteRule` either). You need to use mod_rewrite's `%{QUERY_STRING}` var:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=([0-9]+)($|&)
RewriteRule ^/?page\.php$ http://test.com/profile/info/id/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Added `?` to end of rewritten URL to discard the original query string.

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess the syntax is incorrect. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^page.php?id=([0-9]+)  http://test.com/profile/info/id/$1  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`